# Why is wrapping the subquery with select () necessary?

Tags: postgresql, select

Beginner question: I have a hard time understanding the answer to this postgres [exercise](https://pgexercises.com/questions/updates/insert3.html)

The correct answer is this:

```
insert into cd.facilities 
(facid, name, membercost, guestcost, initialoutlay, monthlymaintenance) 
select (select max(facid)+1 from cd.facilities),'Spa',20,30,100000,800;
```

What I don't understand, is why the following code doesn't work?

```
    insert into cd.facilities 
(facid, name, membercost, guestcost, initialoutlay, monthlymaintenance) 
select max(facid)+1 from cd.facilities,'Spa',20,30,100000,800;
```

error message:

[image]

I tried separately the 2 versions of the subquery:

```
select max(facid)+1 from cd.facilities
```

[image]

```
select (select max(facid)+1 from cd.facilities)
```

[image]

and they seem to give the exact same output. Why is wrapping the subquery with select() necessary here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use brackets query will try to select data not only from `cd.facilities` table but will continue with `'Spa'`, `20`, `30` etc that don't exist.

Comment: tks Svetoslav. I tried wrapping the subquery with brackets, but that gives an error as well:
 
insert into cd.facilities 
(facid, name, membercost, guestcost, initialoutlay, monthlymaintenance) 
(select max(facid)+1 from cd.facilities),'Spa',20,30,100000,800;

Comment: this part is incorrect (select max(facid)+1 from cd.facilities) because now you don't select 'Spa', 20, 30, 100000, 800. Think of your subquery  (select max(facid)+1 from cd.facilities) as an eliminated calculation that should return you a number, and after calculation is done you just add it to your main select statement.

Comment: Oh I see what you you mean. The select wraps the entire list of values. Got it. thank you!!